# Why does creating contained authentication user cause login error?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Creating a contained user in my SQL Server Express 2014 partially contained database, causes exception when performing queries on existing open connections.

Here is the SQL to turn on contained DB authentication and create the database:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

CREATE DATABASE TestContainedUserAuth CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL;
GO

USE TestContainedUserAuth;
GO

CREATE USER TestCreatorUser WITH PASSWORD='Test1234';
GO

ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER TestCreatorUser;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [TestTableID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is the .Net 4.6.1 code for performing the query (please create a console project and paste this in Program.cs, and of course change server and instance name to match yours):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=False;Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestContainedUserAuth;User ID=TestCreatorUser;Password=Test1234"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM TestTable", connection))
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, after running the C# program to perform this query in a loop, run this from SQL Management Studio (BTW, we are fully aware of the security risks associated with contained databases and with dbo users in a contained database):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'MyNewUser') DROP USER MyNewUser;
GO

CREATE USER MyNewUser WITH PASSWORD=N'Abcd1234';
GO
```

After executing `CREATE USER MyNewUser` (which executes successfully) in SQL Management Studio, I'm getting this exception in the C# program:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Login failed for user
>   'S-1-9-3-1497860641-1239606672-4234875017-3655542527'.
>
> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any,
>   should be discarded.

If I modify the code to keep a reference to the connection and **not** open and close the connection for each query I don't get the exception.  So it appears as though the exception is happening when ExecuteNonQuery attempts to re-login on the connection after the connection is obtained from the pool, but I'm not sure.

Additionally if pooling is turned off (`Pooling=False` in the connection string), the exception doesn't occur.

Finally, after this error occurs once on one connection, it seems like existing pooled connections are "healed" and queries executed on existing connections are successful from then on, until another 'CREATE USER' is performed.

Neither keeping a reference to a permanently open connection or turning off pooling is a practical solution to this error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions. We decided to **not use containment**.  The problem does not occur when using non-contained database and non-contained SQL login authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. Its using an old connection from the pool.

Would an acceptable solution be to clear the application pool for that connection?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the idea but there are a couple reasons it won't work for me. 1. The client connections are from many computers and 2. The pools would have to be cleared immediately after the SQL to create the user and alter the roles, before any other thread uses a SQL connection, and this is running in ASP.Net in IIS.

Comment: Is the issue the app running for a user that is dropped and recreated via sql server management studio?  I dont see any way around this other than the app needing a restart OR clearing the app pool on login failed and trying again for this particular use case.  good question!